# How to restrict a document access to only one user.

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, item-level-permissions

How to restrict a document access to only one user; not even Farm account should have access to those documents.

Comment: You also can follow the following question: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/221040/item-level-permission-in-sharepoint-2013/221048#221048 and this will help you out with the same.

Answer (score 2):

You have to break the security hierarchy of the desired document and replace the current permissions the the one you want to have access to the comment. 
Here some good explanations of how to do it.

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/08/24/sharepoint-2013-set-unique-permissions-for-folders-and-documents/

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Edit-and-manage-permissions-for-a-SharePoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782

It is important to state that even setting specific file permissions, the Site Collection Administrators will always have full control access to that file, document or list item.